# localhost:3000/cart, got an error as localhost :3000/api/products/cart 404(Not Found)

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, react-router

I am working on an E-commerce website and adding a 'cart' route on it, but it got the following Error:
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5Jll.png)
The localhost address is :3000/cart, but the error address is from :3000/api/products/cart.(I am using express to fetch data from :http://localhost:5000/api/products)

Also, if I input the address as:" http://localhost:3000/cart/223", the error came out as:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/cart/api/products/cart 404   (Not Found)
```

App.js :

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
      <Route exact path="/products" component={ProductPage}/ >
      <Route path="/:id" component={ProductDetail} />
      <Route path="/cart" component={CartPage} />
      <Route path="/cart/:id" component={CartPage} />
    </Switch>
  )
}

export default App;
```

cartPage.jsx :

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { addToCart } from "../actions/cartActions";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

function CartPage(props) {
  const productId = props.match.params.id;
  const qty = props.location.search? Number(props.location.search.split("=")[1]): 1;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (productId) {
      dispatch(addToCart(productId, qty));
    }
  }, []);

  return <div>Hell world!</div>;
}

export default CartPage;
```

productDetail.jsx:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { detailsProduct } from "../actions/productActions";

function ProductDetail(props) {
  const [qty, setQty] = useState(1);
  const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.productDetails);
  const { product, loading, error } = productDetails;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(detailsProduct(props.match.params.id));
    return () => {//};
  }, []);

  const handleAddToCart = () => {
    props.history.push("/cart/" + props.match.params.id + "?qty=" + qty);
  };

  return ({product.countInStock > 0 && (
    <button onClick={handleAddToCart}>
      Add to Cart
    </button>
  )})
```

`http://localhost:5000/api/products`:

```
[
  {
     name: "Slim Shirt",
     category: "Shirts",
     image: "/img/d2.png",
     price: 60,
     brand: "Nike",
     rating: 4.5,
     numReviews: 10,
     _id: "123",
     countInStock: 0,
   },
   {
     name: "Best Shirt",
     category: "Shirts",
     image: "/img/d3.png",
     price: 50,
     brand: "ads",
     rating: 4.6,
     numReviews: 12,
     _id: "223",
     countInStock: 6,
   },
   ....}
```

server.js:

```
import express from "express";
import { data } from "./data";

const app = express();

app.get("/api/products/:id", (req, res) => {
  const product = data.find((x) => x._id === req.params.id);

  if (product) {
    res.send(product);
  } else {
    res.status(404).send({ msg: "Product Not Found!!"     });
  }
});

app.get("/api/products", (req, res) => {
  res.send(data);
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("server started at http://localhost:5000");
});
```

package.jason:

```
{
 "name": "frontend",
 "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
    .....}
```

//store.js:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, compose, 
applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import {
productDetailsReducer,
productListReducer,
} from "./reducers/productReducers";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { cartReducer } from "./reducers/cartReducers";

const initialState = {};
const reduer = combineReducers({
productList: productListReducer,
productDetails: productDetailsReducer,
cart: cartReducer,
});

const composeEnhancer = 
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const store = createStore(
reduer,
initialState,
composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);
export default store;
```

//productActions.js:

```
const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST });
    const { data } = await axios.get("api/products");
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data 
    });
 } catch (error) {
   dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, payload: 
   error.message });
  }
 };

const detailsProduct = (productId) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
   dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST, payload: 
   productId });
   const { data } = await axios.get("api/products/" + 
     productId);
   dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS, payload: data 
   });
   } catch (error) {
   dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL, payload: 
  error.message });
    }
  };

  export { listProducts, detailsProduct };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue seems to start with the order of the routes rendered by the `Switch` component. Route path order and specificity matters within the `Switch`. The `"/:id"` route path is ***less*** specific than `"/cart"` which is ***less*** specific than `"/cart/:id"`, and so it will be matched and rendered by the `Switch`.

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
  <Route exact path="/products" component={ProductPage} />
  <Route path="/:id" component={ProductDetail} /> // matches "/cart"
  <Route path="/cart" component={CartPage} />     // unreachable route!!
  <Route path="/cart/:id" component={CartPage} /> // unreachable route!!
</Switch>
```

The last two routes are unreachable. The wrong component is rendered when the path is `"/cart"` and an invalid request is made.

ProductDetail dispatches an action that is likely meant to make a fetch request with a proper id, bu `"cart"` is the `id` value with path `"/cart"` matched by the `"/:id"` route.

```
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(detailsProduct(props.match.params.id));
  return () => {};
}, []);
```

## Solution

Reorder the routes in inverse order of path specificity. In most cases doing this also completely removes the need to pepper all the routes with the `exact` prop.

Example:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/cart/:id" component={CartPage} />
  <Route path="/cart" component={CartPage} />
  <Route path="/products" component={ProductPage} />
  <Route path="/:id" component={ProductDetail} />
  <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
</Switch>
```

Note that `"/cart/:id"` is ***more*** specific than `"/cart"`, `"/products"`, and `"/:id"`, and that both `"/cart"` *and* `"/products"` are ***more*** specific than `"/:id"`, and they are *all* ***more*** specific than the last route path `"/"`.

Note also that `react-router-dom@5` allows the `Route` component to use an array of paths for the `path` prop. Keep in mind that the order and specificity still matters within the array. Keep also in mind that *all* routes in the array should be more specific than the paths of routes below/after.

Example:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path={["/cart/:id", "/cart"]} component={CartPage} />
  <Route path="/products" component={ProductPage} />
  <Route path="/:id" component={ProductDetail} />
  <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
</Switch>
```

### API requests

For the requests try using an absolute path, i.e. `axios.get("/api/products/" + productId`) so the request isn't being made from the `"/products"` sub-route. You want the API request path to be something like `"/api/products/123"` instead of `"/products/api/products/123"`.

Example:

```
const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST });
    const { data } = await axios.get("/api/products");
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, payload: error.message });
  }
};

const detailsProduct = (productId) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST, payload: productId });
    const { data } = await axios.get("/api/products/" + productId);
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL, payload: error.message });
  }
};

export { listProducts, detailsProduct };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your cart routes above your /:id route.

Comment: Hi, I moved and it woks! Thanks so much!